What should be optimal basis of choosing specific curve in Openssl Elliptic operations
While trying to generate SSL certificate using
openssl ec 

and
openssl ecparam

utilities, I see a big list of Elliptic curves as output of command
openssl ecparam -list_curves

I'm confused which specific curve should I use. I've this question then what should be the optimal basis of choosing specific curve in Openssl Elliptic operations?

Maybe https://security.stackexchange.com/ is better forum for this question.
